# mysql: consequences of using display width with ZEROFILL

Tags: mysql, join, integer

The documentation says:

> If you store values larger than the display width in an integer column that has the ZEROFILL attribute, you may experience problems when MySQL generates temporary tables for some complicated joins. In these cases, MySQL assumes that the data values fit within the column display width.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Can you provide me with particular examples, illustrating the problem? Or tell me how to recognize queries, which may make it happen?

Comment: Your quote already says what might go wrong … display width = 3 and value = 9123 might(!) lead to MySQL cutting that to either 912 or 123 when creating a temporary table during a complex query, and that will not be what you want.

Comment: @CBroe, I rephrased the question.